# Quicksort Help - Partition

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm implementing my own quicksort iteratively and with recursion.

It gets the first partition fine where numbers on the right side of pivot are greater than and left side less than.

However my partition doesn't seem to partition the right side and only the left.

```
int[] data = {3,5,2,7,11,9,1,88,22};

public void qSort(int[] data, int left, int right){
    int pivot = partition(data,left,right);
    pivot = partition(data,pivot,data.length-1); // Test example for right side only
}

public int partition(int[] data, int left, int right){
    int pivot = left;
    left++;

    while (left <= right){
        while ((left <= right) && (data[left] <= data[pivot])) {
            left++;
        }

        while ((left <= right) && (data[right] >= data[pivot])){
            right--;
        }

        if (left < right){
            int temp = data[left];
            data[left] = data[right];
            data[right] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
        }          
    }

    if (data[right] < data[pivot]){
        int temp = data[right];
        data[right] = data[pivot];
        data[pivot] = temp;
        pivot = right;
    } 

    return pivot;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm stumped :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually your partition implementation works fine, you pass the wrong `left` parameter to `partition` in:

```
pivot = partition(data, pivot, data.length - 1); // Test example for right side only
```

It should be:

```
pivot = partition(data, pivot + 1, data.length - 1); // You need to exclude the pivot itself.
```

Because in your implementation, you choose the left most element as pivot, so if you pass `pivot` as `left` parameter when you try to partition the right part, everything will retain the same because it's already partitioned.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get it working recursively after doing your suggestion :)

Comment: @Ketameme, glad to help :-) BTW, you don't need to pass `pivot` to neither left nor right sub-partition, because it's already in its right place.

Comment: @Ketameme, please consider to accept it as solution if it really resolve your problem:-) Thanks